# how to automatically pull new changes from the mercurial main repository to the local repository

Tags: java, jenkins, numerical

is there a way to pull the latest changes from the main repository of mercurial to the local repository(project)? 
example:
we are two people working on the same project, I want to have my project pull the changes that my friend comment automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, on the mercurial configuration, there is a check box saying, "use repository caches" it was disabled, when i checked it, pull action start to work.